# Firebird 2.5 commit/rollback (using autonomous transaction) in loop

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird-psql

I have to process records in a stored procedure's loop, for example:

```
create or alter procedure process_waiting_records
as
  declare   v_id                type of column my_table.id;
begin
  for
    select
      t.id
    from
      my_table t
    where
      (t.status = 'WAITING_TO_PROCESS')
    order by
      t.created_at
    into
      :v_id
  do
  begin
    execute procedure process_one_record(:v_id);
  end
end ^
```

The problem is when the execution of `process_one_record()` fails (generates any kind of exception), the whole set of modification will be rolled back from the calling code.

The goal would be to process all possible records, I don't really care at this point if some of the records can not be processed, those failed records will be logged in a log table anyway (using autonomous transaction).

I was thinking about to call the `process_one_record()` stored procedure also in an autonomous transaction block with `when any do (dummy code)` clause. However, I think that is not going to work, because that failed transaction will not be rolled back, but committed (referring to this topic: [Firebird 2.5 exception handling within autonomous transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59814545)).

Could some one please point me to the right direction how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need anonymous transactions for this. When an exception is thrown out of a stored procedure, the effects of that stored procedure is automatically undone. If a stored procedure contains `SUSPEND`, only the effects up to the last `SUSPEND` is undone (think of it as a savepoint). For any other forms of rollback, a transaction will need to be explicitly rolled back.

See also [Savepoints and PSQL](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-transacs-psqlandsp) in the Firebird 2.5 Language Reference.

> Transaction control statements are not allowed in PSQL, as that would
> break the atomicity of the statement that calls the procedure.
> However, Firebird does support the raising and handling of exceptions
> in PSQL, so that actions performed in stored procedures and triggers
> can be selectively undone without the entire procedure failing.
>
> Internally, automatic savepoints are used to:
>
> - undo all actions in the `BEGIN...END` block where an exception occurs
> - undo all actions performed by the procedure or trigger or, in for a selectable procedure, all actions performed since the last SUSPEND,
>   when execution terminates prematurely because of an uncaught error or
>   exception
>
> Each PSQL exception handling block is also bounded by automatic system
> savepoints.
>
> NOTE: A `BEGIN...END` block does not itself create an automatic
> savepoint. A savepoint is created only in blocks that contain the WHEN
> statement for handling exceptions.

In this case, as the effects of a single `process_one_record` needs to be undone, but not the whole handling in `process_waiting_records`, you need to allow the exception to be thrown out of `process_one_record`, but catch it for that single procedure invocation.

In short, you need to do something like:

```
for select
  ...
do
begin
  execute procedure process_one_record(:v_id);
  when any do
  begin
    -- do nothing, last call to `process_one_record` was undone
  end
end
```

Comment: so if I understand you correctly with this approach all changes made by the failed process_one_record() will be rolled back automatically (no SUSPEND involved at all) but the previously successful process_one_record() calls still can be commited azt the end of the process_waiting_records?

Comment: @tcxbalage Yes, only the work in a failed call to `process_one_record` is undone, the rest of the work is preserved and can be committed. Be aware that you could actually also catch the exception inside `process_one_record`, the catching of an exception inside a block is what triggers the rollback of the work done in that block, but letting the exception come out of the stored procedure and handling it in the caller is - I think - cleaner.

Comment: I competely missed that "Savepoints and PSQL" lang. ref. all what I was looking for is the exception handling. should have done my research more thoroughly. thanks for your help!